# Authentication system for a REST service?

Tags: rest, security, authentication, client-server

I'm designing a REST service in Node, and I have a plan for authentication and authorization -- but I'm not certain whether there's an unforeseen flaw in the design.

I have a central API server exposed to the Internet. The server also hosts a manager application (which communicates via AJAX), but is authenticated separately from the API, per requirement.

My initial thoughts are to have the server authenticate the user with a login form, then send the user a token (all over HTTPS, of course) that can be sent with each request to the API server for authentication and authorization.

Are there any flaws with this methodology?

Comment: That's more or less what everyone who issues an API key does. You do have to think about things like what happens to compromised tokens - ways to revoke, reissue, ability to revoke any tokens of a compromised user, etc.

Comment: Good point. I'll keep that in mind.